# How can I design a shared schema in Slick 3.0?

Tags: database, scala, dao, slick, spray

I am design a DAO in slick 3.0. The problem I have is that every table in my schema has these 3 common columns:

```
  def id = column[UUID]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
  def createdDate = column[Timestamp]("created_date")
  def updatedDate = column[Timestamp]("updated_date")
```

Is there a design to put them into a trait and extend from all other schema class? I don't want to repeat copy and paste this piece of code multiple times.

One of my class is:

```
class EmailParameterSchema(tag: Tag) extends Table[EmailParameter](tag, "email_parameter") {
  def id = column[UUID]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
  def paramKey = column[String]("param_key")
  def paramValue = column[String]("param_value")
  def emailQueueId = column[UUID]("email_queue_id")
  def createdDate = column[Timestamp]("created_date")
  def updatedDate = column[Timestamp]("updated_date")

  def * = (id, paramKey, paramValue, emailQueueId,createdDate,updatedDate) <> (EmailParameter.tupled, EmailParameter.unapply)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it. This is the shared schema:

```
trait CommonSchema[A] extends Table[A] {
  def id = column[UUID]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
  def createdDate = column[Timestamp]("created_date")
  def updatedDate = column[Timestamp]("updated_date")
}
```

And this is how use it:

```
class EmailParameterSchema(tag: Tag) extends Table[EmailParameter](tag, "email_parameter") with CommonSchema[EmailParameter]{
  def paramKey = column[String]("param_key")
  def paramValue = column[String]("param_value")
  def emailQueueId = column[UUID]("email_queue_id")

  def * = (id, paramKey, paramValue, emailQueueId,createdDate,updatedDate) <> (EmailParameter.tupled, EmailParameter.unapply)
}
```